# Crypto モジュールの encrypt メソッドに指定するパラメータについて

Tags: python, 暗号理論

現在PythonでCryptoモジュールを利用してRSA暗号化をしようとしてるのですが，
1つ不明点があり，質問をさせていただきました．

以下のように，暗号化をしたいのですが，encryptメソッドの2つ目のパラメータ'32'の役割がわからないです．

```py
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
bobKey = RSA.generate(1024)
bobPK = bobKey.publickey()
encrypted_message  = bobPK.encrypt(secret_message, 32)
```

ドキュメントを確認しても，

> - A random parameter (for compatibility only. This value will be ignored)

と記載されており，なぜ実装されているのかが理解出来ません．

このパラメータの役割を知っている方がいらっしゃったら教えていただきたいです．
よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: 参考までに、RSA encryption では使用されていませんが、[ElGamal encryption](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/ElGamal.py#L251)では使用されています。

Comment: 何を与えても無視されるので、役割は無いんじゃないんですかね。下位互換性のために、消せなかっただけで。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/219046